# Is There A Hyphen Limit When Hyphenating Words?

Tags: grammar, hyphens

When creating hyphenated words is there a limit to how many hyphens you can use? I've rarely seen examples exceeding **word-word-word**, and I'm wondering if this is because it's rare that one would need to go beyond that point, or if there is an imposed limit of some kind.

For example, would **word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word** be acceptable, assuming the words used qualified for hyphenation?

Comment: Is there a limit? I guess you're not familiar with the _English-really-doesn't-have-strict-numerical-limits-on-anything_ rule of thumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no hard limit, but *word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word* is pretty silly.  Although there's no rule of grammar preventing you from writing something like this, it's rarely appropriate and never necessary.

Use your common sense—if it looks hard to read, it probably is!  If you find yourself writing something like the above, consider rephrasing.

Comment: +1 But for an exception which strains the rule see [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84296/24489), and in particular the answer from Russell McMahon.